# Do init* functions retain what is passed to them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, retain

I init a navigation controller with:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
```

I wonder if the navigation controller retains firstViewController or that I need to keep it alive. When I release firstViewController, the navigation controller still works. That seems wrong.

Clarifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it needs to keep it around it will `retain` it.  So yeah, you'll be safe to release it if *you* don't need it anymore.  It's not just `initWhatever` methods that have this behaviour - it's the standard operation of the whole memory management model.

Comment: true for everything but delegates. If an init takes a delegate in it will not retain it. This is in line with no one should retain delegates.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. The firstViewController is expressly made to pass on to the UINavigationController through the initWithRootViewController, so *I* don't need it anymore. UINavigationController does, but that's its responsibility.

Thanks for reinforcing that. Can't be done enough.